# Would opening a car door at high speed change the path of the car?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air, drag

If I were to open a standard, four door, four wheel, car on the highway, would the door swing open and possibly tear off? Would the drag that it creates 'reroute' the car (turn it to the direction of the open door)?

Or, would the air rushing past the car push the door closed?

I have been wondering for a while about this question, and have wisely decided not to try it in real life; just in case.

Comment: I can't imagine a door being blown off, since it would very likely just be blown closed and car doors are quite securely held on from my experience.   Maybe if it was a suicide door, then just maybe it gets ripped off, if the car was doing about 150. - but I'm just speculating.

Comment: Hi Dopapp. This is a site for questions about physics. So you might for example want to ask about the equations that describe aerodynamic drag. But as it stands your question is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @JohnRennie - should I just close/delete it, then?

Comment: If you can't think of a way to edit it that might make it appropriate, and you don't want to wait for other people to help you edit it to make it appropriate, then you can delete it. But you're not obligated to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The air would be creating a high pressure in front of it and low pressure behind it, so the force would be pushing the door closed. If you were driving at highway speed backwards the door could be ripped off. To find out whether or not the force is enough to redirect the car, math is necessary. The drag force depends on surface area, airspeed, air density, and drag coefficient.

The drag equation:
$F_d = \frac {1}{2} \rho u C_d A$

$F_d$ is drag force, $\rho$ is the density of air, $u$ is your airspeed, $C_d$ is the drag coefficient, and $A$ is area.

Example car for dimensions: [VW Golf](http://www.the-blueprints.com/blueprints-depot/cars/vw/vw-golf-two-door.GIF)

First, the surface area of the door. Almost every door i've found researching on google is around 1 meter tall and 1 meter wide. It is a bit triangular but factoring that in will not significantly effect the results. Considering the drag equation is never perfectly accurate anyway, it doesn't matter. So $A = 1m^2$.

Next comes the drag coefficient $C_d$, which depends on the friction of the surface and the shape. Surface friction is usually negligible at highway speeds or slower, especially with air on metal/glass. For a square flat plate $C_d$ is $1.17$.

Air density is pretty standard at sea level $1.275kg.m^{-3}$ and highway speed would be about $70mph$ or $110kph$

So far we have $F_d = \frac{1}{2} (1.275)(110)(1.17)(1) = 82N$. That's about $18.5lb$ of force. Enough to push it closed pretty hard, but is it enough to redirect the car? To find out we need to find how far it will move the center of drag of the car and see how much torque it will apply.

Your average modern car has a $C_d$ of $0.26$, speed and air density are the same, and surface area is about $1.7m^2$ for the example car. $F_d = \frac{1}{2}(1.275)(110)(0.26)(1.7) = 31N$ or $7lb$ of force. The drag of the open door is more than double the drag of the entire car. Center of drag will be an average between the center of the car and the center of the door. The two points would be $1m$ apart, so the center of drag is just the ratio between the two drag forces. $\frac{82}{31+82}$. The center of drag would be $0.72m$ from the center of the car.

Now to find the amount of torque applied to the car. $\tau = FR$ The force would be the drag of both components and the radius is the distance from the center. $\tau = 113(0.72)$. Torque $= 81.3N$ or $18.3lb$ of force.

The driver would definitely feel the car pull toward the open door, but it wouldn't cause a cataclysmic crash or a scary swerve. The door would push back on the person holding the door open, so without them, the door would slam shut.

Source for drag coefficients: [engineeringtoolbox.com](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/drag-coefficient-d_627.html)